# Sencha: Cannot satisfy requirements for "ext"

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd

trying to refresh my sencha extjs app and always get this error:

Commands:

sencha app refresh 
sencha app upgrade

Always the same error:

```
[ERR] Cannot satisfy requirements for "ext"!
[ERR]    The following versions cannot be satisfied:
[ERR]       root: ext@5.1.1.451 (No matches!)
[ERR] Cannot resolve package requirements
```

What can I do?

Sencha Cmd: v6.1.3.42 (with last version 6.2.0 I get this error too) 
Core Version 5.0.0 
Extjs Version 5.1.1.451

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is happening because you installed Sencha latest version sometimes ago and then you using previous version of sencha to build or refresh. Check which version of sencha is installed in your system ?

Comment: Thanks. But what can I do now? I made an upgrade: <br /> Sencha Cmd v6.2.0.103
[ERR] Cannot satisfy requirements for "ext"!
[ERR]    The following versions cannot be satisfied:
[ERR]       root: ext@5.1.3.228 (No matches!)
[ERR] Cannot resolve package requirements <br /> Always the same error.

Comment: Which version are you using for your app ?

Comment: As you can see in the previous message, now 6.2.0.103 for the cmd and 5.1.1.451 for extjs

Comment: Ext library is missing it seems. Do one thing go to this folder YourApp\.sencha\workspace\sencha.cfg and in that 2nd last line ext.dir give the path of Ext5.1.1.451. You must have Ext5.1 in your system. do that.

Comment: Also can you tell me what is the path given at `ext.dir` over there

Comment: ..\Documents\src\PrimeNote2\web\PN2\ext

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123845/discussion-between-udid-and-user2075861).

Comment: In my cfg dir is not setted :

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is occurring because your app is not getting path for ext directory and therefore you are getting error like

> [ERR] Cannot satisfy requirements for "ext"! 
>   [ERR] Cannot resolve
>   package requirements

to resolve this open this file `YourApp\.sencha\workspace\sencha.cfg` in your app and in this config file give the path of your ext.dir
example : 
`ext.dir=${workspace.dir}/../../../../Ext6.0.3`

In case if you don't have ext then you can download from this link.[Sencha](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/evaluate/)

Comment: Also make sure the directory exists where  ext.dir  defines it.

Answer (score 1):

With Sencha CMD 6.1 and up, if you want to use the 'app upgrade', you need to configure your framework first. I can't say for sure this will work with ExtJS 5, but it worked for going from 6.

https://twasink.net/2016/09/20/upgrading-to-extjs-6-2/ (see Step 1)