# Sencha init app with extjs6 error

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd

I am trying to follow the [setup guide](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/guides/getting_started/getting_started.html) from extjs. Downloaded the GPL version 6.2.0 in my home folder and executed

```
sencha config --prop sencha.sdk.path=/home/username/sencha-sdks/ext-6.2.0
```

but when I execute the init command I get the following error :

```
sencha app init --ext@6.2.0 --modern MyApp 
Sencha Cmd v6.5.3.6
[INF] Using existing workspace at /home/bivol/myapp
[ERR] Cannot satisfy requirements for "ext"!
[INF]    The following versions are available:
[INF]       5.0.0.970 ( ... compatible back to 4.0)
[INF]       5.0.1.1255 ( ... compatible back to 4.0)
[INF]       5.1.0.107 ( ... compatible back to 4.0)
[INF]       5.1.1.451 ( ... compatible back to 4.0)
[INF]       6.0.0.640 ( ... compatible back to 6.0.0)
[ERR]    The following versions cannot be satisfied:
[ERR]       root: ext@6.2.0 (No matches!)
[ERR] Cannot resolve package requirements
```

Comment: Refer to this i think its the same problem [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611449/sencha-cannot-satisfy-requirements-for-ext)

Comment: @Leroy I saw that question but it is for an existing app already. I am trying to build a new one and following the official docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems the cmd prop is not being saved properly. So you must specify the path to extjs during app init.
I ended up using this command that worked:

```
sencha app init -e /home/username/sencha-sdks/ext-6.2.0 --modern MyApp

Sencha Cmd v6.5.3.6
[INF] Using existing workspace at /home/bivol/myapp
[INF] Copying framework to /home/bivol/myapp/ext
[INF] Added framework ext to workspace.json
[INF] Loading framework from /home/bivol/myapp/ext
```